# Stop execution of one method from exception thrown in another (unrelated) method?

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, async-await, flutter-exception

Is there any way in Flutter to make an exception thrown in one method stop the execution of an unrelated method (i.e. a method that did not invoke the throwing method)?

It's a bit difficult to explain what I mean, but something like this:

```
void tryConnectDevice(Device device){
  await device.connect();
  await device.init();
}


/// This method can be called at any time from an external source, and
/// if `tryConnectDevice` is currently being executed it should be stopped 
/// immediately (i.e. by triggering an exception so that it doesn't 
/// wait for `connect()` or `init()` to finish).
void onDeviceDetached(){
  throw Exception('Device detached, stop tryConnectDevice()');
}
```

I tried experimenting with zones, but nothing so far has worked. Of course I could set some error flag somewhere and check that repeatedly in `Device.connect()` and `Device.init()` and throw if the flag is set, but I would very much prefer if there was a way to throw an exception from `onDeviceDetached` instead, so that the execution of `Device.connect()` or `Device.init()` receives that exception and throws, in turn making `tryConnectDevice()` throw...

Otherwise, what would be the best way to tackle something like this?

Comment: You'd need to expose another method, e.g. `device.cancel()` that took some action. For example, let's say the device was talking over a socket and connect established the socket and init performed a handshake. In this case, device.cancel would close the socket causing connect and init to fail and handle the error of a prematurely closed socket however they normally did that (presumably by returning or throwing)